# Cannot re-install a beta test on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

I have a device and email i'm using as an external beta tester for an iPhone app in test flight. I originally downloaded the app on the test device through an invitation via test flight and worked fine. I deleted the app from the phone just like i would with a local Xcode simulation thinking i could just reload it. I uploaded a new build and sent a new invite to the same user for the new build. I am getting an error that I cannot accept the invite and now the app is stuck in "unavailable" in test flight. Here is what i have tried:

-delete and reload testfligt from the app store and try new invite
-delete all data for test flight on iCloud and re-download test flight and try new invite
-delete and re-add external user from both the test and the external user list

Once i have used an email for a beta test, if I delete that specific copy and then try to accept a new invite, am i just screwed on trying to beta test with that user? That cannot be the case and I have to be missing something obvious. This is driving me up the wall.

Thanks for your help

Comment: what is the status of that user in itunesconnect. Try switch off that user and on again .Save now will send an email try that email to download app

Comment: The user only exists under test flight external user. There are no reported installs or devices. I tried completely deleting the user and adding back in to no avail.